# Reconnect Lightroom catalog with relocated photos

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, workflow

*.t*.txt
In Lightroom, I need to reconnect my catalog with the new location of the photos. Seven years ago there were solutions that worked when photos were in the same folders and the folder structure was the same. Unfortunately, I have completely reorganized the photos. I have changed the folder structure, created new folders, and moved individual photos into these new folders. Basically every photo is in a new location. The metadata, except for location, remains the same and correct. I want to modify the catalog to reflect the new location. I have too many photos to process them individually/ I need an automagical solution, I hope that over the last seven years someone has developed a working solution. Since this data is in a SQL database, all(?) that needs to be done is to change the location info in the record and to modify the associated indexes, Piece of cake right?

Comment: Yes, piece of cake: `update {table} set {column}=replace({column},{from},{to}) where {column} like  '%{from}%'` (though the `where`  clause is not really necessary).